# null pointer exception in hadoop mapper program

Tags: hadoop, nullpointerexception, mapreduce

I wrote a simple code for read a text file and display the same text as output by using Hadoop Map reduce program,Here i am not using reducer using only mapper to display the input text file

I took the mapper  as

```
Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text>
```

but i want my output only Value i don't want to see Key value

I wrote a code in Mapper but it shows the NUllPointerException

```
package com.demo.mr;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.output.NullWriter;
import org.apache.commons.lang.ObjectUtils.Null;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class DemoMR {
    public static class MapperDemo extends
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {
        //public NullWritable result = new NullWritable();
        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            context.write(Null,value);

        }
    }
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf, "Demo MR");
    job.setJarByClass(DemoMR.class);
    job.setMapperClass(MapperDemo.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/home/node1/WordCountInput.txt"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("/home/node1/output"));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should code the map output like below

```
context.write(NullWritable, value)
```

you can use NullWritable in value field if map output have only keys.

In Hadoop, you should use all data types as Writable. it would be easy for serialize/de-serialize data from/to network.

Comment: When i use NullWritable in key Position it shows the error NullWritable can not resolved to be a variable

Comment: Can you pls try NullWritable.get().